# CSS PHP that i am struggling with

Tags: php, css

I am having a hard time figuring out what's going on with a theme for a new script that i just bought.

My site is azngirls.com (don't worry it's not pornographic hahah) and if you go to the frontpage you will see that there is a nav bar on top or header bar that shows Login - Register (Forgot Password) and etc. and that bar is supposed to be on top without any gap but if you go to other parts of the site like for example http://azngirls.com/tos - you will see that there is a gap between that nav bar and the actual top of the website which makes it look awkward when you scroll down. This problem occurs everytime i edit the smallest things inside the php file, as in even if i change a single word or letter it suddenly shows that gap.

Another problem that I am having is that on the same page - on the side bar to the right there is a "Show me" button for Browser Plugins but when i click the link it takes me to a 404 page, but when i click the Tools link in the footer menu it takes me to a page that works.

Thanks alot for any help you guys can give! Really appreciate it!

Comment: You can hire a freelancer to fix your website for about $50. If you have a problem with finding a solution yourself, that's a reason to ask on SO.

Answer (score 0):

you have a huge empty line filled with whitespace between `<body>` and `<meta>` tags. and you included a `<meta>` tag inside a body, as it should be in the `<head>` tag.

Comment: I don't sdee any meta tags inside <body> can you show me which one you are referring to? They seem to be all in <head> for me.

Comment: Use your browser's (Firefox/Chrome/Safari) DOM inspector instead of checking syntax yourself. You will see how bad it is.

Answer (score 0):

As @tpaksu suggested, your html is totally messed up. And there is a easy fix to your problem, just add the following code to your style sheet.

```
.content-infobox {
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I am having a problem trying to fix it myself, i did not just come here without trying to fix it myself. Thanks for the help xiaoyi. I am still working on how to fix the links.

Answer (score 0):

use this code on the respective ID

```
 #id{ 
        margin:0px;
}
```